# Which locator to use for this piece of code which is input field

Tags: angularjs, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I have a question, there is another input field which I do not understand how to use locator for. In the code it is

```
'<input _ngcontent-tvt-19="" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" placeholder="You can search keywords" type="text">
```

I want to fill this field with a value using the code in spec file as

```
'element(by.binding('You can search keywords ')).sendKeys("04");
```

But it does not work. I have also tried with cssContainingText and it did not work. Do you have any idea about the locator or how can I change the code line.

Comment: Could you also post the parent elements of this element? (ideally the more HTML the better) There might be a better way.

Comment: Do you have access to change the element? If so, adding the ID as others said is a solid option.  If not, there are still ways to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use by using xpath, as below it will work

element(by.xpath("//input[@placeholder='You can search keywords']"));

Comment: Happy to hear, Fine :)

Answer (score 1):

Easiest solution would be to add an ID or a class to your input field and then use:

```
element(by.Id(<id>))
```

or :

```
element(by.css(<class_name>))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of examples:

```
$('input[placeholder="You can search keywords"]')

$('input[_ngcontent-tvt-19]')
```

Comment: What will be locator in code above, I guess its incomplete.

Comment: It's complete. Both locators will return your input field. Checkout the shortcut locators https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/locators.md